# Segmentation error with 1D array

Tags: arrays, indexing, segmentation-fault, fortran

Here, I know that A is just a 1D array of length 170.

```
subroutine gonewrong(q,e,A)

implicit none

integer, dimension(:) :: q

integer, dimension(:,:), intent(in) :: e

integer, dimension(size(e,1)*2), intent(out) :: A
print *, A(2)
end subroutine gonewrong
```

When I try to find A(2), for example, it gives me a segmentation fault! e has dimension (85,2).

Would it be because I declared A as an allocatable array in the program I used to compile it with?

The program I used:

```
program prog_1
use module_1
implicit none
integer::qm,a,b,c
integer,allocatable,dimension(:)::q
integer,allocatable,dimension(:,:)::e
!integer, dimension(size(e,1)*2) :: A
a = 5
b = 3
c = 10
allocate(q(a+c))
allocate(e(a+b*c,2))

call subr1(a,b,c,qm,q,e) !Outputs are qm,q and e.
call gonewrong(q,e,A) !gonewrong takes q and e as arguments
end program prog_1
```

Comment: You must show more code! It should be compilable. We must see how you are calling it and how does the program see the interface. Is the subroutine in a module? It should be!

Comment: @VladimirF Yes, it is in a module and compiles. I've edited.

Comment: Wait, how can you have `A` as a scalar integer in the program and then pass it to the subroutine which expects an array? How can that ever compile? Show the **complete** code, the whole module, the commands you use. Compile with some debugging flags (`-g -fcheck=all -Wall`).

Comment: @VladimirF Hi Vladimir. It seems as though you saw the post before I edited for the final time. The command I used is gfortran -o test.exe module_1.f90 prog_1.f90 -llapack - I would show you the full module but it is rather long! and I thought it would only be helpful if I made it short by stating the dimensions of the outputs -- after all, the first subroutine I called works on its own.

Comment: @VladimirF Okay, sure. I'm not sure what you mean by the integer part? Sorry!

Comment: i.e. where have I attempted to put it into an array? I don't see what you mean.

Comment: `a` is a **scalar integer** in `integer::qm,a`. The compiler must complain at teh call to `gonewrong()` because an array is required there. But I was wrong, the compiler does not have to complain, because you don't use `(:)`.

Comment: gonewrong doesn't take lower case a  as neither an argument nor as an output as far as I know

Comment: `a` and `A` is the same thing!!!

Comment: @VladimirF If you see my variable declarations you can see that I declared A as an array - so does that mean that they will be seen as the same? I do apologise for making you frustrated -- I am a total beginner...

Comment: `A` is not declared anything, the line is commented out. Or it was just a minute ago. With both declaration for `a` and `A` it can't compile. Don't make random changes to the code in the question when people take it as a base for their answers. Make sure the code is **exactly** the code you tested.

Answer (score 1):

Another issue to consider is that in the declaration:

```
integer,allocatable,dimension(:,:)::e
integer, dimension(size(e,1)*2) :: A
```

the size of `e` is undefined (zero?) at the time `A` is declared. If the size of `A` depends on the size of `e`, you'll need to either fix the size of `e` at compile time or set `A` to be allocatable and separately allocate it once the size of `e` has been set. The takeaway is that `A` won't dynamically adjust its size as the size of `e` changes. In this case, it looks like `A` is declared with zero length because `size(e)` returns zero because only the shape of `e` has been defined, not its size. Referencing `A(2)` would likely throw a segmentation violation (reading off the end of the array) which would be consistent with what you're observing.

Aside: Many people coming to Fortran from dynamic languages don't realize that Fortran routines are split into at least three "zones"; an initial section containing `use` statements for importing external resources, a declaration section where arguments and local variables are declared, and the body of the routine where executable statements are placed (pedants are encouraged to read the language spec; I'm generalizing here for pragmatism's sake). The `implicit` statement separates the imports from the declarations, and by convention, I separate declarations from executable statements with a  bare `continue` statement. `continue` is considered executable, so the compiler should complain if declarations appear after this first `continue`.

Comment: As I commented, this is caused by the OP changing his code in the question without caring. I will revert it to the sensible state.

Answer (score 0):

The error is quite clear:

```
integer::qm,a
```

makes `a` a single integer number (scalar).

The subroutine requires an array:

```
integer, dimension(size(e,1)*2), intent(out) :: A
```

So you are passing the wrong thing there in:

```
call gonewrong(q,e,A) !gonewrong takes q and e as arguments
```

because Fortran is **case insensitive**! You are passing the scalar integer `a/A` to the subroutine which expects an array.

It is much better to use the same `(:)` inside the subroutine for `A` and let the compiler tell you that you are making an error.

The argument is an array so you must pass an array there.

Note: in your original code you had this line commented out

```
! integer, dimension(size(e,1)*2) :: A
```

when you have both lines

```
integer::qm,a
integer, dimension(size(e,1)*2) :: A
```

the program will not compile because `a/A` is declared twice.

---

What less clear to me is your actual intention. Your comment

```
!gonewrong takes q and e as arguments
```

is really confusing. All three things are arguments of `gonewrong`. `q`, `e` and `A`.

Comment: Great thank you, I have fixed the case error and changed a to L.

Comment: There is no case error... Fortran/FORTRAN is case insensitive, so there is no possibility for a case error other than believing that there is the concept of case.